# PWA after downloading from Google Play show url bar

Tags: google-play, progressive-web-apps, release

Pls would you advise?
I created PWA from Wordpress and put it into Google Play everything went good. App is signed with same SHA256n (used Peter's tool) as in the .well-known/assetlinks.json. Display mode on pwa is set to standalone. [manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqeW.png)
[assetlinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epDo8.png).

SHA256 is same in the google store App signing certificate, Using Peter's Asset Links Tool and in assetlinks.json.

If I just add app from browser using "Add to home screen" it's without url bar.

Please any other idea what could be the issue?

Thanks